# How to look at the code in between the ""

Tags: javascript

How would I go about checking the contents of this string? I know the point would be ot use the brackets, Im just not sure how to do it?

```
match("abcdef","@C2D!")
```

I already have this code I am wanting to remove the user input function and replace it so that it looks at the string and decides if it only contains the text characters a,b,c,d,e,f and if it does it returns true if not it returns false

```
var userinput = prompt('Input characters:');

var lowercase = userinput.toLowerCase();

var allowedcharacters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

function checkWord(sInput, arAllowedWrds) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arAllowedWrds.length; i++) {
        if (sInput.indexOf(arAllowedWrds[i]) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

if (lowercase == allowedcharacters){
  alert(true);
}
else{
  alert(false);
}
```

Comment: What are you checking the contents of the string for? You haven't explained yourself very well. Perhaps you can provide a more meaningful example? (Need more information!)

Comment: Do you mean `"@C2D!".match(/[a-f]/g);`?

Comment: I have updated my question hopefully its more clear now

Comment: Do you want to check userinput if it's limited in abcdef?

Comment: I want to get ride of the user input and for it to read the string like the one at the top match("abcdef","@C2D!") @nick-g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it this:

```
<script>
function checkWord(sInput, allowedcharacters) {
  var regex = new RegExp("^[" + allowedcharacters + "]*$", "i");
  return regex.test(sInput);
}

//
// user input must be only contains alphabet a to f,
// both upper and lowercase are permitted.
//
var allowedcharacters = "abcdef";
var userinput = prompt("Please Input characters in '" + allowedcharacters + "':");

if(userinput) {
  if (checkWord(userinput, allowedcharacters)){
    alert("'" + userinput + "' contains only characters in '" + allowedcharacters + "'.");
  }
  else{
    alert("'" + userinput + "' contains characters out of '" + allowedcharacters + "'.");
  }
}
else{
  alert("userinput is null.");
}

</script>
```

It checks if the user input is limited in [abcdef] range. For example, abc, efde, fedca, but not ypapa, xmama.